# Number of days in a rad calendar asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am working with radcalendar. it displays all months of the year. In any calendar month it displays around 42 days.

I dont want to display more than 31 days in any month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [ShowOtherMonthsDays](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/telerik.web.ui-telerik.web.ui.radcalendar-showothermonthsdays.html)

Comment: thank you very much. I am highlight dates in rad calender from database. it is still highlighted. although no of days in a particular month are quite well. date is not visible but it is highlighted. what to do.